# Firebase cloud function invoked twice

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

We have a cloud function set up with pub/sub triggers.

The function is invoked `topic(NAME).onPublish()`

If the function is invoked when it is cold, it always runs twice.

```
Function execution took 284 ms, finished with status: 'ok' METHOD_NAME METHOD_ID
Received message from pub sub METHOD_NAME METHOD_ID
Function execution started METHOD_NAME METHOD_ID

Function execution took 24271 ms, finished with status: 'ok' METHOD_NAME METHOD_ID
Received message from pub sub METHOD_NAME METHOD_ID
Function execution started METHOD_NAME METHOD_ID
```

After that all future messages only run once, until the function goes cold again.

Is this because it takes a long time for the first invocation to complete and the timeout causes it to be run again? Any way to prevent this?

Comment: Please edit your question to share an MCVE. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @DougStevenson For this particular case we need to create a pub/sub queue, and then deploy a cloud function that subscribes to the pub/sub queue. Depending on weather the timeout plays a role, the cloud function deployed might need to be a large one which takes a while to boot up. I'm unsure how to create an MCVE for this case.

Comment: @DougStevenson My hope was that someone who works on the functions team, or someone who has faced this issue before will be able to confirm if the long boot time plays any role.

Comment: If you want to contact someone at Firebase directly, contact Firebase support.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: I have exactly the same issue.  It doesn't appear to happen all the time, but quite often.

Comment: We could not find a solution for that issue. We shifted to appengine because of it.

Answer (score 1):

Startup time is almost for sure the issue. To verify this, try these:

1. comment out portion of the function until fast, to see if the problem goes away (time it in your local terminal, if you can, using timeit module)
2. increasing `Acknowledgement Deadline` seconds (upon subscription); defaults to 10 so could easily be the problem; try 20, 40 etc
3. ensure that the first time run, the function takes less time than the Timeout value of the function (defaults to 60 seconds - not likely to be the problem)

Comment: The `Acknowledgement Deadline` is set to 300 Seconds. You are right about the default, it's 10s, looks like the cloud function set's it to 300 when creating the subscription. So that's not the issue.

Comment: The pub/sub topic pushes to an appspot.com (App engine) endpoint. The 300 seconds deadline applies to this request. I am not sure if that appspot url internally routes to the deployed cloud function or if there is an app engine application that then forwards the request to cloud functions. Any idea how that works internally?

Comment: The first run time does not exceed 60 seconds, it's always less than 30 seconds.

Comment: @precedurallygenerated Did you try item #1

Comment: I'm trying that out now

Comment: Were you able to get this resolved? I'm having a similar issue with .onPublish...